# Robo Script does not work with different Locales and Dialogs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I'm developing a small Android App und would like to use Firebase Test Lab provided by Google to test it. As it requires some steps (e.g. create a profile) to log into the app I would like to create a robo script to simplify this task for the crawler. I already recorded the script (Nexus 6, english locale) in Android Studio and tried to run the script in Test Lab together with the current APK. However the robo script fails at two points

1) If I use a different locale (e.g. german) for the test run, already the first click on the "skip" label (on the intro-page of the app) fails. I checked the log files and could only find the following lines:

```
02-20 04:26:10.536: I/Robo(7061): Could not find a matching element for a target Robo script action using class name matching!
02-20 04:26:10.536: W/Robo(7061): Could not find a matching element for a target Robo script action!
```

2) If I use the same locale (english) for the test run, all steps go fine. The intro-page is skipped, the profile fields are filled with text. Until the script tries to fill in the birthday of the user. For this a click on a EditText is necessary. A DialogFragment is opened and the selected date is written back to the EditText field. However the robo script is not able to trigger the dialog. The error message is the same as above.

For 1) I thought that the script would use the resourceId of the UI element to identify the element which should be clicked, but it seems that I am wrong (?). For 2) I do not have an idea at all. I replaced the EditText with a TextView for testing pruposes to see if this would work, but it didn't. However setting a default value and skipping the birthday input in the script did.

Does anybody know what causes this problems?

Attached the robo script for your information:

```
[
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663672914,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1550663724071,
    "replacementText": "Skip",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/swipe_button_skip",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "Skip"
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/swipe_tab_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663726441,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 50,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1550663730407,
    "replacementText": "Setup",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/first_start_getting_started",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "Setup"
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 4,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/first_start_button_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663732498,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1550663772693,
    "replacementText": "Test",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/edit_profile_first_name",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/profile_first_name_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/profile_name_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663786396,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1550663791785,
    "replacementText": "Tes",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/edit_profile_last_name",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/profile_last_name_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/profile_name_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663806469,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1550663820411,
    "replacementText": "te@de.de",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/edit_profile_email",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/profile_email_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663843184,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1550663862369,
    "replacementText": "not specified",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/edit_profile_birthday",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "not specified"
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/profile_birthday_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663864926,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1550663869565,
    "replacementText": "OK",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "android:id/button1",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "OK"
      },
      {
        "className": "com.android.internal.widget.ButtonBarLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "android:id/buttonPanel",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "android:id/parentPanel",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663885877,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1550663886040,
    "replacementText": "180",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/edit_profile_height",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 5,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/profile_height_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663905938,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1550663929957,
    "replacementText": "65",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/edit_profile_weight",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 7,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/profile_weight_wrapper",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1550663937596,
    "replacementText": "",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/fab",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/coordinator_layout",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.nsoria.fit:id/fragment_content",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663939942,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1550663956459,
    "replacementText": "OK",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "android:id/button1",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "OK"
      },
      {
        "className": "com.android.internal.widget.ButtonBarLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "android:id/buttonPanel",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "android:id/parentPanel",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663959669,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 2000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "PERMISSIONS_REQUEST",
    "timestamp": 1550663960350,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "requestedPermissions": [
      "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    ],
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663960780,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "PERMISSIONS_REQUEST",
    "timestamp": 1550663970478,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "requestedPermissions": [
      "android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"
    ],
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1550663970581,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  }
]
```

Comment: For 1) I'm just guessing right now, but your script has both the `resourceId` and `text` in the `elementDescriptor` array. It probably tries to match both. You could try to remove the `text` field and see if that unblocks on different locales. For 2) the best is to join the [Firebase Test Lab Slack channel](https://firebase.community/) and post your question and test matrix id. This will allow the team to look in detail on why this is an issue.

Comment: For 1) the Robo indeed uses all the provided fields to match an element, including the locale-specific 'text' field. To make your Robo script portable across locales, you can either manually remove the lines with "text": "<some_text>" in the already recorded script or re-record your script after changing Robo script recording settings in Android Studio (open File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Espresso Test Recorder) to NOT use text and content description for element matching.

Comment: You were right for 1). I removed the text and it worked for the german locale, too. I will try to get help with 2) on the Firebase Test Lab Slack channel.